# Activate particular button on four overlapped buttons in iOS

Tags: ios, button, overlap

I have an app which includes four corners with dragable buttons now i want to drag particular point when a button is tapped. Right now the buttons click get overlapped user click on A it clicks on B and so on.

In a nutshell i want to eradicate the confusion for user it should drag the point which user taps on.

Like the cropping of this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jotnot-scanner-pro-scan-multipage/id307868751?mt=8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please write your question a bit clearer? I'm having trouble understanding what your question is.

Comment: I want exact feature as some scanner app in iOS but the four buttons are not properly working as i have taken four buttons for all corners but when these buttons are close to each other than user is not able to drag the one he wants. It just drag the one which user puts his finger.